# Python - How to sort except one index

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

```
columns=['NAME', 'AB', 'H']
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['Harper', '10', '5'], ['Trout', '10', '5'], ['Ohtani', '10', '5'], ['TOTAL', '30', '15']], columns=columns)
df1 = df.sort_values(by='NAME') 
print(df1)
```

the result is

```
     NAME  AB   H

0  Harper  10   5
2  Ohtani  10   5
3   TOTAL  30  15
1   Trout  10   5
```

I want to sort the dataframe except index of 'TOTAL'.

Comment: `pd` is a slang in French language

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ - Interesting, what does mean it ? :)

Answer (score 5):

Try following code to sort the df by 'NAME' by excluding 'Total':

```
df1 = df[df.NAME!='TOTAL'].sort_values(by='NAME')
```

Output:

```
     NAME  AB  H
0  Harper  10  5
2  Ohtani  10  5
1   Trout  10  5
```

You can append back the 'Total' after sorting by:

```
df1 = df1.append(df[df.NAME=='TOTAL'])
```

Output:

```
     NAME  AB   H
0  Harper  10   5
2  Ohtani  10   5
1   Trout  10   5
3   TOTAL  30  15
```